# R program- Drive distance latitude and longitude between cities

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

```
# Driving Distance - road distance 

library(xlsx)
library(ggmap)

transp<- read.csv2("Finaldata.csv",sep=';',header=T)

dtransp<-subset(transp,select=c(First_CDD_Dealer))

#find unique levels of dealer
unidealer<- unique(transp$First_CDD_Dealer)
unidealer2<-unique(dtransp)
dealcount<- unidealer2

#Makes a list of the unique dealer names
dealcode<-as.list(unidealer2)

#Define matrices
dealerdist<- matrix(nrow=nrow(unidealer2),ncol=nrow(unidealer2))

#Name the columns and rows in matrix

dimnames(dealerdist)<- dealcode
colnames(dealerdist)<- t(dealcount)

for (i in 40:length(unidealer)){

 #will make upper part of distance matrix as using i to reduce length of j-loop  
  for (j in 1:length(unidealer)){

  #i'th dealer position
  from<- as.numeric(unique(subset(transp, First_CDD_Dealer==unidealer[i],        select=(c(First_Dealer_lon,First_Dealer_lat)))))

  #j'th dealer position
  to<- as.numeric(unique(subset(transp, First_CDD_Dealer==unidealer[j], select=(c(First_Dealer_lon,First_Dealer_lat)))))

  # Call google API to calculate distance and travel time
  ddist<- mapdist(from, to, mode = c("driving"),output = c("simple"), messaging = FALSE, sensor = FALSE, language = "en-EN",override_limit = FALSE)


#Makes a distance matrix in km
dealerdist[i,j]<- ddist$km

#Mirror in diagonal to make a symmertrical distance matrix
# dealerdist[j,i]<-dealerdist[i,j]

 } 

}

 #save dealer km distance matrix
 write.csv2(as.matrix(dealerdist), file = "Z:/Project/R/Dealerdist17.csv")

 b <- read.csv2("Dealerdist17.csv",sep=';',header=T)

 write.table(b, file = "Z:/Project/R/dist17.txt")
```

1.Error: is.character(from) is not TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In revgeocode(from) :reverse geocode failed - bad location? location = "-70.8864"reverse geocode failed - bad location? location = "42.1697"

Its strange because sometimes the same code runs from another system for the same dealer loop? Any idea why this is happening ? Is it problem with my coding ?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem where everything worked fine until this error popped up suddenly.

It seems that there's also a limit on the reverse geocoding. If you try to run geocode("someplace, somecountry") you might get this error: "geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".

In short, the geocoding function is not returning a valid value into the mapdist function because of a query limit causing everything to fail.

You can check how many queries you have left with geocodeQueryCheck()